# Get all orders between two dates per day

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Lets say i have 3 orders in my database

```
  1-1-16
  1-4-16
  1-15-16
```

What i want to do is show a graph with orders per day between two dates. For example

1-1-16    /
1-5-16

What i want is

```
 1-1-16      ,1
 1-2-16      ,0
 1-3-16      ,0
 1-4-16      ,1
 1-5-16      ,0
```

How should i get the data for the dates when there are no orders?
I have an Order model with a created_at field where i can run the querys on.

Currently I get the orders grouped by date like this:

```
$variable = Order::select('created_at', DB::raw('sum(total) as totals'), DB::raw('sum(shipping) as totalshipping'))->groupBy(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'))->OrderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This gives me orders per day, but not **returns the days without orders**.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: and also, how do you display the graph? Do you use a js plugin for your graph which accepts json?

Comment: @gokigooooks i will post my code in a few minutes i can get the orders grouped per date but only if there is an order already. The js plugin is irrelevant the question is about getting the data but ive added it for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;   
$oders = Order::select('id', 'created_at')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('d'); // grouping by date
});
```

For dates that you don't have orders for them:

```
$start = new DateTime( '2016-01-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2016-05-01' );
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$range = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $range as $day )
  // check if the $orders[i]->created_at !=  $day->format("Y-m-d")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this dosnt give me results for dates with no orders.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating the dates within your desired range then attaching the orders within the date

to create the range with carbon

**note** this is assuming you are using carbon objects with the start date, end date, and order dates.

if **not** I strongly suggest you use them they are built-in for laravel. timestamps(created_at,updated_at) are by default carbon objects.

```
$start_date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '11-06-2016'); 
$end_date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '11-23-2016');
$date_range = [];


//containing the dates from the query and count of orders
$i = 0;
for($date = $start_date; $date->lte($end_date); $date->addDay()) {

    $date_range[$i]['date'] = $date->format('m-d-Y');
    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        if($date==$orders->created_at)
        {
             $date_range[$i]['orders'] = $order->totals;  
        }
        else
        {
             $dates_range[$i]['orders'] = 0;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

now you can do something like

```
   foreach($date_range as $date)
   {
       echo 'date: '.$date[date]. orders : .$date['orders'];
   }
```